# Alamofire/Swift2: initializing variable in case .Success callback throws EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, swift2, alamofire

```
        Alamofire.request(.POST, endpoint, parameters: params)
    .responseJSON { request, response, result in

        switch result {
            case .Success(let json):
            var customerData:[String:AnyObject] = [String:AnyObject]()
// throws: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

I get the same error if i declare the var outside the request and try to set `customerData["whatever"] = "some value"`

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code.

```
 var customerData = NSDictionary() as! [String : AnyObject]
 customerData["One"] = 433
 customerData["Two"] = "2323"

 print(customerData)
 Output:
 ["One": 433, "Two": 2323]
```

Its working good in Playground xcode 7.1 beta

Comment: Kewl, but that's not the problem. var customerData = [String:AnyObject]() also works in xcode playground bruh...

Comment: the problem is the var in the context of the .Success callback

Comment: turns out I was a case of pebkac, was trying to access a dictionary key that didn't exist (mispelld), so un-stoked by this revelation breaux :(  Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) is a hell of a way to say so huh? anyway, thanks for the help Narendra.